# Creating (Dropping) Multiple Tables in One Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Is it possible to create (self.up) multiple tables in one rails three migration.  If this is possible, what is the conventional wisdom on using such an approach.  Something tells me it would be better form to keep one table per migration, but I'd just thought I check with some more seasoned ruby on railers.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using a GEM that requires you to drop all related tables when you make a change. Up until now, I have been doing it one table at a time, but it occurred to me that things would go much master if I could create and drop the tables in batches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overall idea of migrations is to have the database schema in version control. So I personally think that it is more important to have one migration per "feature". For example, if you have an application for Pleople(name, prename) and you want to add a phone number, you would add this change to a migration. If, with the phone number you want to implement some remote lookup, you might need a caching table. I would still add that to the same migration.

There is one advantage of splitting up table creations: You can manually rewind the migrations per table.